# WPF Render Window Frame

Tags: wpf, window, render

I've been searching everywhere and tried various solutions, but none worked for me, so here is the question.

How can I render window without calling show() and hide() - getting it initialized. Its a simple gui containing grids, buttons and other native controls.

Many thanks!

Comment: You mind to show us a little bit of code. We can help you better if we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its really not much to show. Basically

Window w = new Window();
w.RenderOperation();
w.SetParameters(); // such as set button location on a canvas for example

And at some point later open the window and see the correct gui data.
w.Show();